# C++ callback to C#: an unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: c#, c++

In my project I have a .net core 3.1 C# wpf app and an unmanaged C++ dll. From the C++ dll I have to implement a callback. The code below runs about 30 seconds. After that I get the following error message on the line '_observer(message);': An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Thanks for any hints

C++ dll:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TestDll_AddObserver(void (__cdecl *observer)(const char* message));

void (__cdecl *_observer)(const char* message);

void __cdecl TestDll_AddObserver(void (__cdecl *observer)(const char* message))
{
    _observer = observer;
}

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID data)
{
    char message[] = "Hello world!\n";

    for (;;)
    {
        if (_observer != nullptr)
        {
            _observer(message); // Line the exception occurs
        }
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, MainThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

C# app:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void MessageDelegate(IntPtr messagePointer);

    [DllImport("TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void TestDll_AddObserver(MessageDelegate messageHandler);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestDll_AddObserver(OnMessage);
    }

    private static void OnMessage(IntPtr messagePointer)
    {
        if (messagePointer != null)
        {
            string message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(messagePointer);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `TestDll_AddObserver(OnMessage);` is sugar for `TestDll_AddObserver(new MessageDelegate(OnMessage));` -- that `MessageDelegate` instance needs to be kept alive (e.g. in a field) so long as the C++ code might try to invoke it. As it stands, the GC will come along and collect it at some point, and then you will crash when the C++ side tries to invoke it

Comment: @canton7 Are you sure a field with no read access outside of that function would not actually be optimized away?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes. Fields cannot be optimized away, not least because they're always visible to reflection (and therefore serialization, etc). It would also cause observable changes to behaviour, in cases such as this one

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was exactly that problem. Now it works perfectly.